Laravel Dynamic Custom SMTP
I'm currently working on a Laravel multivendor application and need some help with implementing custom SMTP settings for each vendor. The goal is to ensure that whenever an email is triggered, it is sent using the specific vendor's SMTP settings.
I’ve also implemented Queues for Jobs and notifications. However, I’m facing an issue where even though I try to change the SMTP configuration dynamically before triggering the email, it still sends emails via the default ENV configuration.
Before sending Email I update config values
Config::set('mail.host', $host);
Config::set('mail.port', $port);
Config::set('mail.username', $username);
Config::set('mail.password', $password);


Has anyone worked on something similar or come across this issue? Any suggestions or examples from similar projects would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

likely you are sending emails via queues, but the jobs them self have no idea what tenant dispatched the job.
